# Best languages/frameworks for imaging Linux app

Tags: linux, tiff, kde-plasma, imaging, scanning

I'm looking for the best tool/language/library/framework to develop a document scanning/imaging/indexing application that must run on KDE/Linux. The application must provide the following functionality:

1) Document scanning (simple and multipage) in B/W, save the scanned images in TIFF format with CCITT Group 4 compression.

2) Allow the operator to view/browse/zoom the document in a window, and manually enter index information on a predefined dialog box (5-6 fields max).

3) Generate an XML file with the index metadata, then upload both the TIFF and XML files to an FTP server for further processing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Ernesto.

Answer (score 1):

For KDE 4 you have libksane, which depending on your distro, may be separate package or part of kdegraphics package.

As for choice of development languages, referrer to KDE's documentation.
http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages

Comment: SANE is by far the most popular scanner access library on Linux, so ksane is definitely the way to go on KDE.